# Conditionally load .cake files

Tags: cakebuild

I use CAKE 0.22.0.

Depending on the arguments passed into `build.cake`, I want to load different `.cake` files. E.g., if the parameter `VisualStudioVersion` has the value `2013`, I want to load the `vs2013dlls.cake` file; if it has the value `2015`, then I want to load the `vs2015dlls.cake` file; etc.

Looking at [the CAKE page on preprocessor directives](https://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/preprocessor-directives), I don't see any information on preprocessor keywords such as `#if` and `#else`.

I would prefer not to copy the contents of the other `.cake` files into `build.cake`, lest `build.cake` becomes much too bloated.

How can I load `.cake` files conditionally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently there's no support for conditionals when it comes to script loading the 0.23.0 will add if def support but pre processor directives are processed as same level/priority so won't help for your specific problem.

What you could do though is create a small bootstrapper cake script that pulls in the pieces needed for your specific scenarios.

### Example using CakeExecuteExpression

```
var visualStudioVersion = Argument("VisualStudioVersion", "2017");
var statements = new List<string>();
var currentDir = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./"));

statements.Add("#load \"{0}/common.cake\"");
switch(visualStudioVersion)
{
    case "2013":
        statements.Add("#load \"{0}/vs2013.cake\"");
        break;
    case "2017":
        statements.Add("#load \"{0}/vs2017.cake\"");
        break;
    default:
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Unknown VisualStudioVersion: {0}", visualStudioVersion));
}

var expression = string.Format(
                    string.Join(
                        "\r\n",
                        statements
                        ),
                    currentDir
                    );

CakeExecuteExpression(
    expression
);
```

For above if argument VisualStudioVersion is set to 2017 or no argument specified then it'll load

- common.cake
- vs2017.cake

If argument VisualStudioVersion is set to 2013 then it'll load

- common.cake
- vs2013.cake

### Example using CakeExecuteScript

Perhaps less complex is to just provide to different entry points i.e. have a `build.cake` file call either `vs2013.cake` or `vs2017.cake` depending on argument.

#### common.cake

```
Information("This will execute regardless version!") ;
```

#### vs2013.cake

```
#load "common.cake"
Information("Hello VS2013!");
```

#### vs2017.cake

```
#load "common.cake"
Information("Hello VS2017!");
```

#### build.cake

```
var visualStudioVersion = Argument("VisualStudioVersion", "2017");

switch(visualStudioVersion)
{
    case "2013":
        CakeExecuteScript("vs2013.cake");
        break;
    case "2017":
        CakeExecuteScript("vs2017.cake");
        break;
    default:
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Unknown VisualStudioVersion: {0}", visualStudioVersion));
}
```

#### 2017 output

```
cake .\executescript.cake
```

Will output

`This will execute regardless version!`

`Hello VS2017!`

#### 2013 output

```
cake .\executescript.cake --VisualStudioVersion=2013
```

will output

`This will execute regardless version!`

`Hello VS2013!`